# How to stop Steam from installing itself to other users?

Tags: steam

I installed Steam and I want it to be installed only on my account. Everytime when someone else logs in, Steam tries to update itself to complete the installation for that user. I don't want to do that for every user becouse the update is really big and I have limited HDD space, so is it possible to stop Steam doing that?

Comment: Could you add more information to the question? Some simple things like your Cron, Startup, Steam install details, etc.?

Comment: I've installed on a vanilla Ubuntu 14.10 the normal Steam from the page and the problem has appeared on a second user (the popup looks similar to the dropbox install-one, I can send a screenshot if it helps)

Answer (score -1):

When a user logs in, Steam should not automatically open. It's likely that Steam is still set to open in their Startup Applications. Disabling it there should prevent it from starting when a user logs in.

Comment: It's not listed in the startup apps (any obvious places) and this still happens. It appears as though Steam has some kind global hook for login.

Comment: Well this is strange because I have steam installed and this never happens. 14.10. Could I get more details on the question?